# How to find partial pressures of gases only given their percentages?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

How do I find partial pressures if I am only given their percentages? Where do I begin?

Example: Assume $\ce{O}=21\%$ , $\ce{N}=78\%$ , $\ce{Ar}=1\%$ by volume. How would I calculate the partial pressures if total pressure is $\pu{1 atm}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Pressures of gasses are additive.** For example, 1 atm X plus 1 atm Y makes 2 atm total pressure. Because all the components of a mixed gas are at the same temperature and pressure, the fraction of each component by volume is also the same fraction of the total pressure.

Comment: Is this generally true or only for ideal gasses?!

Comment: Yes, but it works quite well in any "normal" range of densities.